# Determining smallest number of common dependency bundles for a matrix of NPM dependencies

Tags: npm, dependency-management

Say I've got a handful of NPM package specs (a spec is like `@scope/package-name@version`), and they share a few common dependencies, and a list of versions for each package. So, where both `a` and `b` depend on `dep-a` and `dep-b`, at different versions:

```
a@1.0.0
a@1.1.0
b@1.0.0
b@1.0.1
```

I need to generate the smallest number of semver-compatible bundles of the shared dependencies. To do that I need a function that returns a list of highest-semver-compatible dependency specs for each combination of packages in the matrix:

So for example, if `a@1.0.0` and `b@2.0.0` both depend on `dep-a@^1.2.3` and `dep-b@^1.1.0`, I might get this result:

```js
getDeps('a@1.0.0', 'b@2.0.0');
// ['dep-a@1.2.3', 'dep-b@1.1.0']
```

And if the next patch of `a` and the next minor release of `b` haven't changed bump the dependency versions, I could get the same result:

```js
getDeps('a@1.0.1', 'b@2.1.0');
// ['dep-a@1.2.3', 'dep-b@1.1.0']
```

But then, if `a@1.1` bumps it's dependency version in a way which is semver-compatible with `b`, then I would get a different result:

```js
getDeps('a@1.1.0', 'b@2.1.0');
// ['dep-a@1.3.0', 'dep-b@1.1.0']
```

Is there already a tool that can do that?